# Zsh: How can I disable the "searching..."-feature?

Tags: linux, shell, search, autocomplete, zsh

When I misspell a command or directory and press `enter`, `zsh` first says `command not found`, but then displays the annoying `"searching..."` text, which can take a few seconds to show me, that nothing has been found anyway ;)

So, from my point of view, it's an anti-feature.

How can I disable it?

*Notes:

- I'm using OpenSuse 11.2. Could it be an OpenSuse-specific feature?

- My .zshrc is empty.

- I'm **not** talking about that autocomplete that comes after pressing `tab`*

Sample from console:

```
me@myhost:~> testt [enter]
zsh: command not found: testt
testt: searching...
testt: command not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which version of zsh are you running?

```
echo $ZSH_VERSION
```

Your personal `.zshrc` might be empty, but have you checked the system files?

```
man zsh
```

At the end of the default man page, it will usually list the installation specific system file locations (usually in /etc)

```
   /etc/zsh/zshenv
   /etc/zsh/zprofile
   /etc/zsh/zshrc
   /etc/zsh/zlogin
   /etc/zsh/zlogout    (installation-specific - /etc is the default)
```

Do any of these files include any changes?  I've found most Linux distributions tend to install `command-not-found`.  I prefer to not use it and uninstall it.

Comment: Yes! The uninstallation of `command-not-found` did the job! ;)

Answer (score -3):

Never actually used `zsh`, but this seems like what you want:

```
unsetopt correct
unsetopt correctall
```

Comment: No, doesn't help.